# Unable to open another page from a link inside a modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a button inside a bootstrap modal to link to another page on my site. I haven't been able to do this for some reason. Here is what the code inside the modal looks like:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="another-page.php" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">Read More</a>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning">Close</button>
</div><!-- End modal-footer -->
```

Clicking on the Read More button will close the modal, but not open the link to another-page.php. Is there another tag that I'm missing?

Comment: are there any errors being thrown in the console?

Answer (score 1):

use this command instead of `data-dismiss="modal"` in link

```
onclick="$('#modalId').modal('hide')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute from your button...

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="another-page.php" class="btn btn-success">Read More</a>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning">Close</button>
</div><!-- End modal-footer -->
```

**Example...**

```js
$('#openBtn').click(function(){
 $('#myModal').modal({show:true})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="openBtn">Open modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <p>My modal content here…</p>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="btn btn-success">Read More</a>
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was it, I was just missing the http:// stuff first apparently. Thank you very much!